# What's better for a blog + ecommerce website: WordPress or Symfony?

Tags: wordpress, symfony, web, content-management-system, e-commerce

**Hi!** I’m writing here because I would love to get your opinion on something.

I’m want to build a website, kind of a blog mixed with ecommerce (shop with crm, only online products).

After talking with a few developers most of them recommend a Wordpress with Woocommerce. Although some of them says that PHP framework (eg. Symfony) is going to be far better option for such a project.

I would really appreciate your opinion on that. Which one would you recommend: WP or Symfony? And why?

**A little bit more about my website:**
- blog: I’m going to post a few types of content, each type has a different layout,
- shop: 40+ products in 3 categories. After a purchase customer gets an access to a product page (videos, text, JPGs, PDFs),
- landing pages for products must be highly customizable (something like a WP’s page builder seems nice to me) because each product is different and also I’m going to do a lot of A/B testing,
- speed: I’m going to use a cloud servers but website itself has to be very fast,
- efficient database: because it’s going to grow, more content, products, customers and orders. Not super fast, but constantly.

**So what would you recommend and why?**

Comment: While the question is far too broad, I personally also do not understand it. WordPress is a CMS, a ready made "website" which you can extend with various plugins and themes. Symfony is a programming framework, you have to program the website yourself. And yes, bundles help alot. Another important question is: With which of these are you already familiar? etc

Answer (score 2):

Symfony is now an eCommerce app. I think what that developer said is that he will build a custom one for you. As for that, you are basically asking "what's better: using Woocommerce or a custom app?"

Of course it's better building a custom eCommerce app. Woocommerce is very unsecure and has lots of updates that can ruin your store. Wordpress as a platform had some real issues with security, which now are not so serious, yet the plugins in their repository are not always verified and can have severe security problems. These can be solved, of course, yet that makes lots of work.

It also written in less efficient way then what a developer can build for you. As a blogging platform it can be great and fast but after adding plugins (and from my experience, clients can't stop themeselves from adding plugins) loading a page becomes a nightmare.

If you have enough money go for the custom option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very opinionated question (which is not quite fit for SO) so you're not going to get many answers. In fact I should not even write this answer... :-)

CMS software (like WordPress) is very quick to start with, but you have to accept the features it offers and the way it works. If you have a very customized project, you will hit a wall sooner or later.

Using a framework means that the developer will build the site as you wish. Usually takes much more time and money, but it will be tailored around your needs.